# WIX: Setting a registry value from a dialog checkbox

Tags: wix, windows-installer

Using Wix for the first time in 10+ years, and first time with forms/dialog entry.

Have a property defined more or less like this:

```
<Property Id="THE_FLAG">
  <RegistrySearch Id="SearchTheFlag"  Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\$(var.Manufacturer)\$(var.SimpleProductName)" Name="the_flag"  Win64="$(var.Win64)" Type="raw" />
</Property>
```

Have a control in a form to set it:

```
<Control Id="TheFlagCheckBox" Type="CheckBox" X="45" Y="80" Width="220" Height="17" Property="THE_FLAG" CheckBoxValue="1" Text="Flag for something" />
```

At the end I want to write it:

```
<RegistryKey Root='HKLM' Key='SOFTWARE\$(var.Manufacturer)\$(var.SimpleProductName)' ForceCreateOnInstall='yes' >
    <RegistryValue Name='the_flag'     Type ='integer' Value='[THE_FLAG]' />
</RegistryKey>
```

If I select the checkbox, it sets the registry value. However, if I don't check the checkbox, then I get a warning when running the installer about not being able to acces the registry value. I think it is because the "value" of "THE_FLAG" is null or the empty string. I want to avoid the nasty warning to the user. I took over some code, and the previous owner used all strings for obviously DWORD values...maybe to get around the warning.

Can I set some conditionals or set the value of THE_FLAG to "0" if it is "" or null?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following to your authoring:

```
<SetProperty Id="THE_FLAG" Value="0" Before="InstallInitialize" Sequence="execute">NOT THE_FLAG</SetProperty>
```

This will set the value of `THE_FLAG` to `"0"` if it's blank (in MSI, null and empty string are both blank) before the registry writes are done. A reasonable alternate value for `Before` is `"WriteRegistryValues"`.

Comment: I did change the Before to WriteRegistryValues... and the condition I have now is "NOT (THE_FLAG=1)". I had tried this before without any luck...getting compiler errors when the condition was wrapped in a ![CDATA] type block...except it was giving a weird error not pointing to the condition. Just putting it in there sort of normal works. Thanks.